# boost asio async_read_some reading only pieces of data

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

i have a c++ server which is using boost::asio to do read/write operations - writing out the messages works fine - yet for some reason i cannot get the read to work

the message i am sending to it from the client is 15 16 bit unsigned shorts - my test message is this:

```
1, 34, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

now on the server i'm seeing things like this constantly.  the read is often broken up and/or multiplied by 256

this is one run sending it twice

```
reading length = 8: [1 34 7 0 0 0 0 0]
reading length = 3: [1024 0 0]
reading length = 3: [0 0 0]
reading length = 8: [1 34 7 0 0 0 0 0]
reading length = 6: [1024 0 0 0 0 0]
```

this is the second run sending it twice

```
reading length = 8: [1 34 7 0 0 0 0 0]
reading length = 6: [1024 0 0 0 0 0]
reading length = 6: [1 34 7 0 0 0]
reading length = 1: [0] 
reading length = 0: []
reading length = 0: []
reading length = 2: [0 0]
reading length = 2: [0 0]
reading length = 1: [0]
```

this is the third run sending it once (i don't know what happened here)

```
reading length = 14: [256 8704 1792 0 0 0 0 0 1024 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Here is the actual server read code

```
void Session::start(void) {
  msg_interface->add_msg_listener(this);
  _socket.async_read_some(
    boost::asio::buffer(_read_data_buffer, READ_DATA_BUFFER_LENGTH),
    boost::bind(&Session::handle_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void Session::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
  if (error) {
    msg_interface->remove_msg_listener(this);
    delete this;
  } else {
    if (bytes_transferred != 0) {
      // print what we've received
      const int length = bytes_transferred / sizeof(uint16_t);
      std::cout << "reading length = " << length << ": [";
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        const uint16_t data = ntohs(_read_data_buffer[i]);
        std::cout << data;
        if (i != length - 1) {
          std::cout << " ";
        }
      }
      std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
    }
    _socket.async_read_some(
      boost::asio::buffer(_read_data_buffer, READ_DATA_BUFFER_LENGTH),
      boost::bind(&Session::handle_read, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }
}
```

the variables are as follows

```
const int READ_DATA_BUFFER_LENGTH = 1024;

class AbstractSession {
protected:
  uint16_t _read_data_buffer[READ_DATA_BUFFER_LENGTH];
...
```

There is one thing - i am using the same IO service to write messages when they are received (the server is talking to an old interface and sends out the messages it receives to all the clients) and to read messages from the clients.  could using the same io service for both cause this to happen?

Any thoughts on what i should do to fix this?

Comment: delete this - in handle_read is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does what it is supposed to do - it reads as much data as it can. This is why the  function [`async_read_some`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/async_read_some.html) name ends with "some" - it reads "some" bytes and does not promise to do more than that. Documentation also says the following:

> Consider using the async_read function if you need to ensure that the
>   requested amount of data is read before the asynchronous operation
>   completes.

Which seems like your case unless you re-work your receiver to handle partial reads.

Comment: well - i guess what i'm wondering, i'm going to need to read 3 input messages with different lengths - is there any reason it's only reading a certain amount like this instead of reading the complete message? also - when i use async_read it doesn't read the data completely (14 instead of 15) then the messages become out of sync (first word of next message read correctly is appended to last message - next message is missing first word) and i never get a correct message - i'm testing on localhost too so i can't see why its dropping data

Comment: i also notice, if i send the message once a second from the client it will eventually sync up and start reading correctly on the server - i'm really confused as to why this is happening as well - and then once out of every 28 or 30 so messages it will just multiply it by 256

Comment: @seanchriste: TCP/IP, and especially non-blocking read/write goes beyond the scope of comments. The only thing I can suggest is getting some good book about it. You are not supposed to be able to send or receive a complete message, it is a streaming protocol...

Comment: the async_read ended up fixing it - i am still confused as to why using async_read_some would randomly multiply the data it read (seems like it was shifting bits somewhere along the line) - but async read ended up fixing that problem - i haven't seen any ordering issues, thank you

Comment: No problem. Async read some is not multiplying anything. It gets from the OS TCP/IP stack as much data is there is available for the process. How many bytes are there depends on the MTU size, on how the other part actually sends data (i.e. nagle is enabled or disabled) etc. In either case don't think of those numbers as "magic" numbers - assume nothing. What you see is what you get. What `async_read` is doing is just getting those chunks of data until it has enough bytes, then passes that data in one chunk to you. So under the hood it does nothing technically useful. Just simplifies your life.